# Como desenvolver um Acesso Remoto

Tags: c#, vb.net

Gostaria de desenvolver um sistema que possibilitasse conectar uma máquina em outra máquina e me desse o controle total dessa 2° maquina, Ex: Team Viewer, Ammy Admin, Log me In.

Não gostaria de fazer nada muito avançado, apenas algo que eu ficasse independente desses softwares de terceiros.

Bem, vocês teriam uma ideia de como começar isso?

Algum artigo do conhecimento de vocês que possar me auxiliar nesse desenvolvimento?

Também se é algo que compensa investir tempo para desenvolver?

Comment: estude sockets.

Comment: Sua pergunta é ampla de mais, mas como uma resposta eu diria para você fazer uma lista de requisitos do seu software, quais os recursos ele vai ter e suas prioridades, depois disso aborde cada um dos recursos de forma individual e tente desenvolver os recursos de forma individual.

Comment: - Pedro, eu acabei encontrando uma dll chamada VNCSharp, com ela consegui conectar em outro micro usando o VNC Server como Host.
- Minha ideia é quase isso, quero apenas conectar no computador(Cliente) e transferir arquivos, porém não quero ficar dependendo do VNCServer

Comment: @FelipeWalleg Então você pode [edit] sua pergunta para algo mais específico usando essa DLL, e de preferência já mostrando algo que você tenha tentado com ela. Inclua também no mínimo um link para documentação da DLL.